# How to Convert string column to Date column in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: date, pyspark

I have a string column(DOB) like below:

**DOB**

1973-Jun-28 
1978-May-02

I want to convert this to *Date* type. I tried the below but it's showing *null* value in the output. I tried other answers from stackoverflow but to no avail.

```
df.withColumn('DOB', to_date('DOB', 'yyyy-MMM-dd'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you test below code and verify if this is working?

Ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

```
cat <<EOF >test.csv     
DOB
1973-Jun-28
1978-May-02
EOF
```

pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
df = spark.read.csv('test.csv',header=True)    
df.withColumn('DOB', to_date('DOB', 'yyyy-MMM-dd')).show()

+----------+
|       DOB|
+----------+
|1973-06-28|
|1978-05-02|
+----------+
```

Comment: I figured out the issue, there is a space before the date value in the column. After removing space it worked. Can you tell me how to get **1973-Jun-28** as output if **1973-06-28** is the input?